# Making a node go in the direction of a swipe (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swipe

I'm making a game in SpriteKit using Swift, and I want to be able to swipe on the screen and have a ball go in that direction. I already have the ball created and its just named "ball" as an SKSpriteNode. I already have it moving around the screen but I just need it to change directions towards swipes that take place. If I can't do this with swipes then I would consider taps.

Also, I have a border the size of the screen. Here is the code for that:

```
let worldBorder = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody = worldBorder
    self.physicsBody?.friction = 0
```

The border is already functioning as a border, but I need to keep it that way for when I start swiping.

Comment: I want to see the code of you moving the ball around the screen.

Comment: There is no need for that

Comment: Hi Andy. I've seen in a couple of your questions that you're making fairly direct "write this for me" requests. We try to discourage that here. I appreciate you're a new developer, and perhaps even that there are a number of folks out there who would be happy to write a whole solution for you. Nevertheless, we don't want Stack Overflow to be known as a source of free labour, and while it does not apply to you, there are surely a lot of lazy programmers out there who would love for other people to do their work for them.

Comment: Therefore, please allow people to answer in their own way, even if that means you have to do some of the implementation yourself. This will have the additional benefit that you get some hands-on experience too. Thanks!